При запуске не видит коги или выдает ошибку
При запуске условно готового к работе кода выдает ошибку:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] Системе не удается найти указанный путь: './cogs'

Файл создан и лежит в каталоге правильно. Перерыла все, просто не знаю уже как это решить. Если не выдает ошибку выше, то пишет другую (при запуске другого кода, все файлы есть):
disnake.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension "cogs.Economy" raised an error: NameError: name "disnake" is not defined 

Или еще такую ошибку, все установлено, подключено и тд, но работать не хочет даже с готового кода:
disnake.ext.commands.errors.NoEntryPointError: Extension 'cogs' has no 'setup' function.


import os
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands

intents = disnake.Intents.all() 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents, test_guilds=[123456789])

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready!")

for file in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if file.endswith(".py"):
        bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{file[:-3]}")

bot.run("token")


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример


FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] Системе не удается найти указанный путь: './cogs'

Данная ошибка может возникать, если папка с когами находится где-то в другой директории. Если она у Вас находится, предположим, в какой-то папке example, то Вы так и должны прописать в коде ./example/cogs. В ином случае она должна находиться в корневой папке с ботом.

disnake.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension "cogs.Economy" raised an error: NameError: name "disnake" is not defined

Эта ошибка может означать, что Вы не импортировали библиотеку disnake в ког и пытаетесь обратиться к ней

disnake.ext.commands.errors.NoEntryPointError: Extension 'cogs' has no 'setup' function.

Данная ошибка означает, что Вы не прописали шаблон кога, который необходим для его работы. Подробнее про это можно прочесть в документации самой библиотеки.
Все-таки думаю, что для более подробного разбора проблемы потребуется сам ког, ибо по мейн классу мало что можно сказать.
